# How to render inset box-shadow over the child element's background?

Tags: html, css

Run the snippet below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container1 {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px red;
  width: min-content;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: min-content;
}

.container2::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px red;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="container1">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="text">Some text</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="text">Some text</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Is there a way to rewrite the code for the **container1**'s red box shadow to be above the yellow background (or in general any background including a picture)?

*One way to do it, which resolves the issue, is utilising pseudo-elements (so, the rendered **container2** is how it intended to be), but I don't particularly like this solution and hope there is a way to do the same without introducing new dom elements (just utilising css).*

Comment: The pseudo elements are not DOM elements. You cannot find them in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned `container2` to show the **intended** structure, I removed that from my code. here is how I do this task with the help of **position** CSS property:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .container1 {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  
  .inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .text {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="container1">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="text">Some text</div>
    </div>
    <!--
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="text">Some text</div>
    </div>
    -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Without setting width and height:

If you don't want to set width and height you could use `display:flex` on `.container1` element as follow:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
  }
 
  .container1 {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px red;
    width: 35%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  
  .inner {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .inner img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .text {
  color: #1415FF;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="container1">
        <div class="inner">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque id temporibus cumque, magnam blanditiis voluptate vel nisi. Fugit itaque quod inventore, optio dolor magnam ipsa, temporibus rerum qui error deserunt?
            <!-- <img src="birthday.png" alt=""> -->
        </div>
        <div class="text">Some text some text Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto quo assumenda veniam voluptatum beatae impedit doloremque, libero quam placeat. Illo, totam. Deleniti nihil fugiat impedit, rerum ullam hic mollitia quia! impedit doloremque, libero quam placeat. Illo, totam. Deleniti nihil fugiat impedit, rer</div>
    </div>
    <!--
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="text">Some text</div>
    </div>
    -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used `width: 35%` in `.container1` just because of we usually set a relative width for elements but you can remove it. You could also put `img` tag inside `.inner` class and I think that works correctly.

Comment: It's a great answer and I'm about to mark it as correct for given question. Just one clarification: is there a way to rewrite it for the condition when widths and heights of the .inner and .text are unknown (so, the dimensions of the container is also unknown). I've set width and height in my example to simplify it (so, not to add any content), but in the real example there is some content (picture and text) which determines the width and height for the container.

Comment: @olegzhermal if I understood your goal correctly I added some code in the answer that uses ```display:flex``` instead of "position" property.